# Datatable with exlusion on the search filter with a certain class

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a HTML table, in fact I have more tables acrross my site.
So I created a class called `datatable`, which covers most of my generic table needs.
For exports, like PDF and Excel, I managed to exclude the column with the class `ignore`.

I want to exclude the column with the `ignore` class dynamically. 
I want to be abble to set more columns with the `ignore` class and avoid the filter to go trough these columns.
It's not necesery that there will be a `button` or `a` elements, so please avoid suggesting that I just exclude these.

In a specific case, I have a name `Edit Valvasor`, and I want the filter to find the row with when I type `"Edit"` in the filter and ignore the columns with `Edit buttons`.

Example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/t1h9ugqa/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datatable').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [
      [15, 25, 50, -1],
      [15, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    pageLength: 25,
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    aaSorting: [],
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'copy',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':not(.ignore)',
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':not(.ignore)',
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':not(.ignore)',
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'pdf',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':not(.ignore)',
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'print',
        customize: function(win) {
          $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
          $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

          $(win.document.body).find('table')
            .addClass('compact')
            .css('font-size', 'inherit');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
      <th class="ignore"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Edit Valvasor</td>
      <td>1034</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Samuel Grixis</td>
      <td>655</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Martin Kempinsky</td>
      <td>153</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add:

```
  columnDefs: [
        { searchable: false, targets: 3 }
    ],
```

the code in the example is like: //target is the number of column

```
  $('.datatable').DataTable({
lengthMenu: [
  [15, 25, 50, -1],
  [15, 25, 50, "All"]
],columnDefs: [
        { searchable: false, targets: 3 }
    ],
pageLength: 25,
dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
aaSorting: [],
buttons: [{
    extend: 'copy',
    exportOptions: {
      columns: ':not(.ignore)',
    }
```

Comment: You might read my post again. I don't want to set datatables options in javascript. I want to set a class on a table header